# How to turn a Json output of Multiple URLs into a list

Tags: python, arrays, json, list

I am parsing data through a json file and obtaining multiple URLs, around 50.

below is part of the command I used to pull out just the URLs

```
results = json.loads(results)
    for repo in results:
        DevOps_url = (repo['remoteUrl'])
        print(DevOps_url)
```

The output looks something like this:

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

https://sjdfnlajsdfljhasdfajdfhlkajsdfhajsdfhlajksdfh

etc.

How can I grab those URLs and put them all into one list so I can parse through the list for each URL?  I have tried the .split() method and that just puts each individual URL into its own list and thats not what I want.

I want it to look something like this
["url","url","url",etc.] in the output.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `urls = [repo['remoteUrl'] for repo in results]`

Comment: You've got the `DevOps_url`, so just append that to a list. Tim Roberts above shows the quick way to do that with a list comprehension instead of the for loop.

Comment: Thank you Tim! that worked out perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `append` to add urls from loop to new list:

```py
results = json.loads(results)

all_urls = []
for repo in results:
    all_urls.append(repo['remoteUrl'])
```

Also you could use list comprehension to do the same in one line:

```py
results = json.loads(results)
    
all_urls = [repo['remoteUrl'] for repo in results]
```

Then you could iterate over created urls with for loop like so:

```py
for url in all_urls:
    print(url)
```

Comment: That is really good to know, Thank you!

Comment: @Connor.Ryan-UC good that it helps you, so, please, consider marking answer as 'accepted'

Answer (score 0):

It could help you:

```
import json;

file = open("./json.json")
loaded = json.load(file);
file.close()

# List for each value of json's key
list_of_content = []

# Get all keys of the json file and their value
for key in loaded:
    list_of_content.append(loaded[key])

for an_value in list_of_content:
    #Do something with each value...
    print(type(an_value))
    print(an_value)
    # etc...
```

Comment: You should close the file, usually it's done with `with` keyword and context manager. Also, snake_case is prefered over camelCase in stuff names